# I am trying to run and existing code but when I try to run the code the error shows "No module named fetch"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fetch

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`[image]

trying to install fetch using pip install fetch but gives error as in the picture below

Comment: Please post code and errors as plain text.  Posting as an image makes it harder for us to help.

Comment: You could try to run: pip install -U setuptools

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the program was written in Python <3, as `file()` is a function that is not supported in Python 3.

Comment: should i downgrade my python version or is there any other way to use fetch module

Comment: I assume it should work if you downgrade your Python version.